# Rails Net::HTTP.post_form API returns 500 Internal Error although it returns correct response through PostMan

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get the API Token from this api.
https://docs.bigmarker.com/#login

Basically below is the API format and it works with PostMan as well

curl -i -X POST --data "email=youremail@email.com&password=yourpassword" https://www.bigmarker.com/api/v1/members/login

I didn't specify any Headers, Just use the POST form data with email & password.

And this is my rails code.

require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

> uri = URI("https://www.bigmarker.com/api/v1/members/login")

> res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {'email' => email, 'passowrd' => password})

But it returns  HTTP 500 Error.
#<Net::HTTPInternalServerError 500 Internal Server Error readbody=true>

Any idea?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can just vouch for this tool: https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.
There was a spelling error.
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {'email' => email, 'passowrd' => password})
'passowrd' should be 'password'